# In Hyperledger Fabric Composer, how do I send events?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

In a Hyperledger chaincode, an event can be sent using the following command:

```
stub.SetEvent("<event name>", "<payload>")
```

In Fabric Composer (specifically in the logic.js file), how do I send a similar event?

And how do I listen to this event in a Node.js application so that my UI can notify the user if a particular event happened already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are actively working on this at the moment. You can follow progress here:
https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/66

Answer (score -1):

You define the event in your .cto file like this:

```
event BasicEvent {
}
```

You emit the event from the logic.js like this:

```
// emit BasicEvent
var factory = getFactory();
var basicEvent = factory.newEvent('<your namespace>', 'BasicEvent');
emit(basicEvent);
```

Source: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/business-network/publishing-events.html